# C programming: how to pass variables from one function to another?

Tags: c, pointers

After I declare a pointer, I set up a pointee. And then I include the pointer in the parameters of another function in hopes of passing the value contained in the pointee to that function. For some reason this is not working out, could somebody help me?

```
int main()
{
  int *ptr1, *ptr2, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
  ptr1 = &count1;
  ptr2 = &count2; //sets up the pointees
  records(ptr1, ptr2, filename);

  printf("%d %d\n", count1, count2);//after the loop in the function records, count1 should hold the value 43 and count2 15, however I don't think I passed the values back to main correctly because this print statement prints 0 both count1 and count2
  return 0;
}

FILE* records(int* ptr1, int *ptr2, const char* filename)
{
  FILE* fp;
  int count1 = 0, count2 = 0

  while()//omitted because not really relevant to my question

  printf("%d %d\n", count1, count2)//when I compile the program, count1 is 43 and count2 is 15
  return fp;
}

void initialize(int *ptr1, int *ptr2)
{
  printf("%d %d", count1, count2);//for some reason the values 43 and 15 are not printed? I thought I had included the pointers in the parameters, so the values should pass?
}
```

Comment: records() is never called. Is this the correct code?

Comment: redo your example code snippet and make sure it compiles.

Comment: Please just put the code that does not work without 'ommitted ...' etc.

Comment: -1 for wasting my time by not supplying reasonable code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Trim the code! where is `initialize` called?

Comment: And -1 for not having made the effort to study all this at least at some basic level. You don't even seem to be aware of how a pointer is supposed to work nor how functions are called. This is so fundamental that you should know it (after having gone through a beginner-level C language tutorial several times).

Comment: Provide the entire code, o/p of the above code will be always be zero as printf in record will always print the local scope of variables count1 and count2 which has been initialized to zero, if u intended to print the value of counts in main. dereference the pointer as *ptr1 and *ptr1

Answer (score 1):

In your `records` function, you have declared *new* variables with the same names, `count1` and `count2`.  These are different than the ones in `main`.  If you want to use the variables from main, you should replace `count1` with `(*ptr1)` and `count2` with `(*ptr2)` in `records`, so it's using the pointers to access the variables in `main`.

To be clear, in `records` you should get rid of `int count1 = 0, count2 = 0`, *then* replace the usage of each of those with `(*ptr1)` and `(*ptr2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code supplied just does this:

```
int main()
{
  int *ptr1, *ptr2, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
  ptr1 = &count1;
  ptr2 = &count2; //sets up the pointees

  printf("%d %d\n", count1, count2);//
  return 0;
}
```

Guess you need a little extra: Try calling a few functions - try `records`

Comment: Sorry, but yes I did call the function, but the values did not pass.

Comment: Sorry - did not guess you called 'records' somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In `initialize` and `records`, you are trying to reference the non-global count variables, in order to print these values you might as well use pointer values you passed. To do this dereference the `ptr` variables (with *) in the `printf` call:

```
printf("%d %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);
```

If you do not intend to modify the count variables, then you have no need to actually pass the pointers, and you can just directly pass the count variables.